# Does "RT-PCR" denote "real-time PCR" or "reverse transcription PCR"?

Tags: pcr

I often find the term "RT-PCR" used in articles without any further qualification. Searching for the meaning of the acronym sometimes leads to "real-time polymerase chain reaction" and sometimes "reverse transcription polymerase chain reaction." I understand that reverse transcription PCR uses a reverse transcriptase to convert RNA to DNA, which is then amplified by the usual PCR method. I'm not sure I understand what real-time PCR is, but it sounds to be distinct from reverse transcription PCR. Are these distinct methods that happen to have the same abbreviation? Or do they somehow mean the same thing? What is usually meant by the acronym "RT-PCR"? Is there some context I can use to distinguish them?

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95268/rt-pcr-not-seeing-how-it-can-measure-mrna-expression-levels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RT-PCR: Not seeing how it can measure mRNA expression levels](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95268/rt-pcr-not-seeing-how-it-can-measure-mrna-expression-levels)

Comment: I find those answers somewhat confusing. This statement for instance seems contradictory to me: "RT-qPCR refers to real-time quantitative PCR, but some organizations refrain from any reference to quantitation (because it's really only semi-quantitative), instead using the nomenclature rRT-PCR (reverse transcription real-time PCR, I guess)."

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no real and hard definition and it can mean both, depending on the context.

Comment: Real-time PCR is used to **quantify** a target in real time, thus is sometimes called quantitative PCR (qPCR). Basically, any mention of Ct or Cq values indicates a real-time PCR methodology. If they are quantifying a DNA target, it's likely referring to real-time PCR (aka qPCR). If they are using it to detect (not quantify) a target from RNA, it's probably reverse-transcription PCR. If they are quantifying an RNA target (like gene expression from mRNA), it's likely RT-qPCR (real time reverse transcription PCR).

Comment: PCR means (piece of DNA) amplification with 2 primers, a polymerase, free nucleotides and temperature cycling (to favor (un)hybridization and polymerization). For RNA viruses, prior to PCR there is RNA extraction and reverse transcription to DNA. In qPCR a fluorescent probe is added in the PCR reaction, when hybridizing (with the target piece of DNA) and [cut by the polymerase ExoN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TaqMan) and excited by some light the fluorescent tag emits some detectable light. An alternative is to use electrophoresis to obtain the amplification product, followed by sequencing.

Comment: @MikeyC That was the answer I was looking for: it that states the definitions in a systematic and unambiguous way. If it were an answer and not a comment, I would accept it.

Comment: FWIW, it seems like the field is coalescing around RT-PCR meaning reverse transcriptase and qPCR meaning real-time. RT-qPCR is the combination of the two. However, there are always going to be exceptions, so context is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Real-time PCR is used to **quantify** a PCR target by measuring some indicator of target amplification in real time after each amplification cycle, thus it is sometimes(often) called quantitative PCR (qPCR). The key to distinguishing between reverse transcription PCR and real-time PCR in the context of a paper or protocol is to look at the starting material being used and the data output.

If the source material is RNA, it needs to be reverse-transcribed into cDNA before PCR amplification. And if they're showing quantification *of a specific target*, it's likely a real-time PCR of some sort. Quantification of a gene target from normal **DNA** is likely a standard real-time PCR (aka qPCR). Quantification of an **RNA** target (like gene expression from mRNA), is likely quantitative reverse transcription PCR (RT-qPCR). The same goes for if the starting material is cDNA (end product of an RNA reverse transcription reaction). Lastly, any mention of Ct or Cq values (or delta-Ct, or delta-delta-Ct) generally indicates a real-time quantitative methodology.

If they are citing the use of RT-PCR to simply confirm the presence or absence of a target (sometimes called endpoint PCR) or to amplify it for downstream applications like sequencing, with no mention of specific target quantification, it's likely a standard reverse-transcription PCR.

There are exceptions to some of these rules, but it should help get you through most literature with some idea of what methods are being used.

Edit: In the past few days, I've seen multiple papers using "RT-PCR" as shorthand (I guess) when they were talking about RT-qPCR or rRT-PCR. Like I said, always exceptions to the rule. But as long as you read the methods it should be simple enough to figure out.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is it incorrect?

Comment: An addition: real time PCR or qPCR requires a a dye which binds to dsDNA. This will give you readings of RFU (relative fluorescence units) per Cycle. In RT-qPCR the dye binds to the dsDNA from the conversion of ssRNA by RT.